# How to implement my own byte array creation and disposal

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

**BACKGROUND:**

In running my app through a profiler, it looks like the hotspots are all involved in allocating a large number of temporary new byte[] arrays.

In one run under CLR Profiler, a few short (3-5 seconds worth of CPU time outside the profiler) produced over a gigabyte of garbage, the majority of it byte[] allocation, and this triggered over 500 collections.

In some cases it appears that the application is spending upwards of 10% of its CPU time performing collections.

Clearly a rewrite is in order.

So, I am thinking of replacing the new byte[] allocations with a pool class that could reuse the buffer at a later time.

Something like this ...

```
{
 byte[] temp = Pool.AllocateBuffer(1024);
 ...
 }
```

**QUESTION:**

How can I force the application to call code in the routine Pool.deAllocate(temp) when temp is no longer needed.

In the above code fragment, when temp is a Pool allocated byte[] buffer, but when it goes out of scope it gets deleted. Not a real problem, but doesn't get reused by the pool.

I know I could replace the "return 0;" with "Pool.deAllocate(temp); return 0", but I'm trying to force the recovery to occur.

Is this even remotely possible?

Comment: Are they your own code's array allocations or are they caused by .NET Framework methods?

Comment: My own code array allocations

Comment: +1 for profiling before optimizing! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement a `Buffer` class which implements `IDisposable` and returns the buffer to the pool when it's disposed. You can then give access to the underlying byte array, and *so long as everyone plays nicely* you can take advantage of reuse.

Be warned though:

- Your buffers will quickly end up in gen 2, which may not be ideal for other reasons
- If a malicious piece of code keeps a reference to the byte array, they could spy on data used by other code
- You need to remember to dispose of buffers at the right time.

I actually have some code in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) to do this - see `CachingBufferManager`, `CachedBuffer` etc. I can't say I've used it much, mind you... and from what I remember, I made it a bit more complicated than I really needed to...

EDIT: To respond to the comments...

- You can't *force* application code to release buffers, no. There's no automatic release mechanism in C# - a `using` statement is the closest we've got.
- You could implement an implicit conversion to `byte[]` in your buffer class to allow you to call methods which have byte array parameters. Personally I'm not much of a fan of implicit conversions, but it's certainly available as an option.

Comment: The disposable makes it more obvious that the programmer shall do something after use (dispose), but the original poster asked for a possibility to FORCE that. I don't believe that is possible.

Comment: I was trying to get around using a different class, because I call a large number of routines with byte[] in the parameter list.  When I tried to use a u8Buffer class, I would get the "Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'u8Buffer[]' error.  Is there an easy workaround?

Comment: @Noah: You could provide an implicit conversion to `byte[]` in your class. I'm not sure I'd recommend it, mind you.

Comment: Time I learned a bit more about GC generations. Any good resource on the subject?

Comment: CLR via C#? I haven't checked, but I'd be mortified if it didn't explain the GC in a lot of detail :)

Comment: Jeffrey spends 64 pages on the GC.